# Is there any way to play video APL?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have implemented APL on my skill but for some reason I can’t play youtube videos. Is there anyway I can do this?

I’m using APL interface

Answer (score 2):

APL "Video" component does support playing videos but those videos must be of a format supported by the device, namely, an .mp4.

Is not possible to use a YouTube link as your source video in an APL response. If you are using, youtube URLs, are not video URLs at all. They are HTML web-pages which include a streaming video

More information can be found on "video properties" section of our "APL.Presentation.APL Interface Reference" documentation:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-interface.html#video-properties

The request sent to your skill's back-end will contain a Viewport.video.codecs array. This array will specify what types of video formats are supported by the device which made the request. An example of this array has been provided here:

```
"video": {
   "codecs": [
      "H_264_42",
      "H_264_41"
   ]
}
```